# How to make an UPI app like PhonePay or Google Pay and what is the Process?

Tags: google-pay, upi

I wanted to know how I can make a app like Phone pay or Google Pay.

from my research I know that I need a company and partnership with a bank.

but I want to know *what things we should implement* from our side if we partnered with bank and what things bank and NPCI handles.